# SMB 3 & Windows 7

Tags: azure, smbfs

I currently map a drive letter in Windows 10 to an Azure Files account using the provided http/SMB3 connection mapping and this works great.
It doesn't however work on another pc running Windows 7.

I understand that Windows 7 does not support SMB3, but is there possibly another way around this?  Is it even remotely possible to map a Windows 7 drive letter to an Azure Files account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible. [Mount an Azure File share and access the share in Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows) states it clearly: Windows 7 has SMB 2.1.

> In order to mount an Azure File share outside of the Azure region it
>   is hosted in, such as on-premises or in a different Azure region, the
>   OS must support SMB 3.0.

Azure Files are mountable in Azure VM using SMB 2.1, because there's no need for [encryption](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/openspecification/2012/10/05/encryption-in-smb-3-0-a-protocol-perspective/), which is a new feature in SMB 3.0. Connections from on-premises must be encrypted.